# Searching in Oxford Dictionary

Tags: java, android, database, file, search

I am an Android Developer, i am creating a Dictionary like app.I have maintained my dictionary in a text file. I want to search in my dictionary for the keyword entered by the user. My dictionary has 35000+ entries in it. What is the best way to do it? Do i have to do a binary search, a hashing technique or a trie?

I have tried hashing but creating a proper hash function in ascending order and binary search over it is very tedious.

This is my first question here. Please tell me if i go wrong any where.

Comment: The OED has a lot more than 35,000 entries in it. :-) (More than 600k, I believe.) Even the concise edition has 240,000...

Comment: So how this info answers OP Q?

Comment: @apomene It doesn't answer the question, it's a comment.  One that notes the scale of 35k words might be wrong, and the OP might need to consider an even larger data set.

Comment: @apomene: If it were an answer, I would have posted it as an answer. I was just noting that the OP referred to "Oxford dictionary" and then said "35000+" entries. (I suspect he doesn't really mean "Oxford".) :-)

Comment: @T.J Crowder you are very true but i gave just a hint about the number of contents in my dictionary.I shouldn't have used Oxford in my title...

Comment: @turbo as T.J correctly implies "OXFORD" doesnt go to OPs implementation, however 35000 is sth that has do with it the number of contents is his dict, otherwise he would mention it

Comment: imho, best solution will be to ditch text file, and go with database, so database handle all search for you, but if you think you can do it better, try indexing

Comment: The best way is probably not writing that part yourself because managing a large dataset requires memory management, hashing is just a minor problem. Look at SQLite (maybe [FTS](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) or maybe [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) or whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Here are some good string search algorithms:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm
I recommend the:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, a tree search can solve this kind of problem, but definitely a text file is not going to help.
You could try converting your file to SQLite (which has proven stability, simplicity and speed) and indexing the **word** table so the searches can be a lot faster compared to that of plain text.

Hope it helps.